# Alignment of subcategories on category page if more than 4

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

It displays four subcategories in single line, if i add minimum 4 in magento main-category pages,,... but if i add one more subcategory, then it takes only 3 per row. How to debug this. I want to display 4 subcategories per row
I have add static block to display subcategories.

```
<ul class="catblocks">
<li>
<a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}other/ludo.html">
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ludo.jpg"}}" alt="ludo" />
    <span>Ludo</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}other/paraolympic.html">
        <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/paraolympic.jpg"}}" alt="paraolympic" />
        <span>Paraolympic</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}other/travel-game.html">
        <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/travel-game.jpg"}}" alt="travel-game" />
        <span>Travel-Game</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}other/carrom.html">
        <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/carrom.jpg"}}" alt="carrom" />
        <span>Carrom</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Fishing

Chess

Dart

[image: proper alignment if 4 subcategories]

[image: aligment is not proper if i add more than 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are add category static then make your html like below

```
<ul>
   <li>First category of first row</li>
   <li>second category of first row</li>
   <li>third category of first row</li>
   <li>Fourth category of first row</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>First category of second row</li>
   <li>second category of second row</li>
   <li>third category of second row</li>
   <li>Fourth category of second row</li>
</ul>
```

style ul as below

```
<style>
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thank u , i got the solution

Comment: Any suggestion on how to achive the collapsible sub categories over parent categories:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155925/collapsible-sidebar-category-with-images-in-magento